# The best way to write a script that takes data from one field and appends it to another

Tags: metadata

I have a house number field that if it contains data, the data needs to be be moved (appended) to another (street address) field.

This is a one-time operation that needs to be done to all the records in the Salesforce database, after which the house number field will be deleted.

What would be the best approach to do it?

Comment: you can use salesforce workbench to do it. Run a SOQL to export the data out. in Excel transfer the data to the other field and then use the same sheet to update the data back to salesforce. You have to include the Id field in the export. https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best i can think of as it is a temporary solution so you write and execute your code snippet from developer console, please run the below code : -

```
List<Account> lst_Account = [Select Id,AccountNumber,Number_Of_Address__c from Account];// you can use filter based on your logic

if(lst_Account.size()>0){
    for(Account acc : lst_Account){
        if(acc.AccountNumber!=null){
            acc.AccountNumber = acc.AccountNumber+String.valueOf(acc.Number_Of_Address__c); 
        }
        else{
            acc.AccountNumber = String.valueOf(acc.Number_Of_Address__c);   
        }
    }

    update lst_Account;
}
```

it will solve your purpose.